How to apply FFT to buffer to find spefic frequencies
I Am doing a small project which boils down to transferring text over a 3.5mm jack from my main laptop to my notebook, i used for the main part which is responsible for producing the audio, however i still need to code the receiver
While i have found multiple examples on the internet of code which i have used, none detail a method to use numpy's FFT function to get the loudest frequency, and check if it matches a table of frequencies
import pyaudio
import numpy as magic
import keyboard

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 1
LISSEN = 0
INDEX = 0

print("Press q to quit")

def keycheck(): 
    keyboard.wait("q")
    return 1

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
print("listening")

while (LISSEN == 0):
    frames = []
    for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
        data = stream.read(CHUNK)
        frames.append(data)
    LISSEN = keycheck()
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

Up to this point this is the code i came up with, it does record, how would i be able to introduce FFT to the frames and find the loudest frequency?
